# How can I uninstall Softmaker Office 2012 if I downloaded their Deb?

Tags: uninstall

I downloaded Softmaker Office 2012 from their website as a deb and installed it. How do I now remove it?

Is it done in terminal? If so what is the command? I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 on a laptop.

Comment: It depends on how you installed it. Did you download a .deb file? Was it installed by running a script, such as `install.sh`? Did you compile it yourself by running a few commands like `make` and `install`? **Please edit your question above and this information.**

Answer (score 5):

This depends on what the software is and also how well it was made ... but in general: normally I would expect an uninstall option in the directory where the software resides.

If not ...

- open a termimal, go to the directory with `cd` and do a remove (`rm`) of the files or directory those files reside in from the termimal.
- or navigate with Nautilus to the directory where it is installed, select it and hit delete.

If the software created all kinds of configuration files this will force you to manually track and remove them. Also: you also will need to manually stop the service if applicable preferbly before removing the software.

---

In this case:  [softmaker](http://www.softmaker.com/english/tipslinux_en.htm) can be removed with this command.

```
sudo dpkg -r softmaker-office-2012
```

if installed with the .DEB file. If you used the tar.gz file then there is a script

```
sudo uninstallsmoffice12
```

that removes it.

Comment: It was a deb file that I downloaded. I'll check, thank you.

Comment: @Orosjopie found the removal instruction on their website ;)

Comment: I've tried this command and I contacted softmaker and gave me the same command, but I get this error: requested operation requires superuser privilege. How can I fix this or get superuser privilege. I do login to the laptop as a administrator.

Comment: @Orosjopie if that is the notice add "sudo" in front of it.

Comment: Thanks, I got the software removed.The command worked very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Since all other answers are outdated and not working, here is the working answer.

First open your terminal and enter

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep softmaker
```

to know what components are installed on you PC. This will give you like following output:

```
softmaker-freeoffice-2016:i386          install
```

Now you know what is installed so to remove with the following:

```
sudo dpkg -r "component name"
```

i.e. for given output: `sudo dpkg -r softmaker-freeoffice-2016:i386`

that should solve everyone's problem.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/619026)

Comment: @kevinbowen edited

Answer (score 0):

Check if the application is listed in Ubuntu Software (centre), under the 'installed' tab.
If it is , then there is a 'remove' option.