# How to uninstall softmaker freeoffice

Tags: command-line, apt, dpkg

I downloaded FreeOffice from [here.](http://www.freeoffice.com/en/download-freeoffice-mobile-office)
Now I am trying to uninstall it by doing this command:

```
sudo dpkg -r softmaker-office
```

And it isn't working.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get remove softmaker-office`?

Comment: please refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347106/how-can-i-uninstall-softmaker-office-2012-if-i-downloaded-their-deb/347108#347108)

Comment: @Marc : no work mate, i got this message 'E: Unable to locate package softmaker-office'

Comment: @Ravan : not a success either

Comment: @6warrior do this :  `dpkg -l | grep softmake*`. Share the output.

Comment: @6warrior "no success"?? what is the error?...run this `sudo dpkg -r softmaker-office-2012` please comment after that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since all other answers are outdated and not working, here is the working answer.

First open your terminal and enter

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep softmaker
```

to know what components are installed on you PC. This will give you like following output:

```
softmaker-freeoffice-2016:i386          install
```

Now you know what is installed so to remove with the following:

```
sudo dpkg -r "component name"
```

i.e. for given output: `sudo dpkg -r softmaker-freeoffice-2016:i386`

that should solve everyone's problem.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the freeoffice directory in your home directory. (If the folder can't be found there, but you know you have the software installed, execute `sudo find / -iname freeoffice`) Delete that folder and all of its contents (either by dragging it to the trash and emptying the trash can, or my executing `sudo -rf freeoffice` from its parent folder.)

There is also a .softmaker folder either in ~/ or in / (if the program was installed as root). Delete it also.

Go to `~/.local/share/applications` (or `/usr/local/share/appliations` or `/usr/share/application`) and execute `sudo rm *-free.desktop`
to remove the icons associated with the programs. This will also remove the programs from the "Open With" menu.

Finally, there is a *SoftMaker* directory in `~/` (or `/`), which should also be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Appending to Aizuddin Zali's `grep` command:

after running the command `dpkg -l | grep softmake*` , i noted that the package name was softmaker-freeoffice-2016

Then, ran command, `sudo apt-get remove softmaker-freeoffice-2016`  . That's all.

Answer (score -5):

First, change to root user instance

```
sudo su
```

This installs locate if you don't have it.

```
apt install -y mlocate
```

Update files' location database

```
updatedb
```

Locate uninstaller, get first of the list and run it

```
locate uninstallfreeoffice|head -1|sh
```

Comment: piping the first locate result into sh in a root shell is a bad idea. At least check the result first!

Comment: you probably would like to tell the user how to exit the root-shell. I can't see a reason for entering it. sudo + command works fine and makes less trouble in newbies hand.