# How to uninstall Softmaker's FreeOffice 2018?

Tags: uninstall

I tried Softmaker's FreeOffice and did not like much. I am trying to uninstall it, but could not get through.

I even tried to follow a suggestion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/681966/how-to-uninstall-softmaker-freeoffice). My system encounters an error stating that the software is not installed, whereas when I open files, they all open in Softmaker's FreeOffice.

Package downloaded from [here](https://www.freeoffice.com/en/download/applications)

```
dpkg --list | grep softmaker 
ii   softmaker-freeoffice-2018   2928   amd64   SoftMaker FreeOffice is a complete office suite

$ sudo apt purge $(dpkg --list | grep softmaker | awk '{print $2}') --dry-run 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done 
The following packages will be REMOVED: 
  softmaker-freeoffice-2018* 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 8 not upgraded. 
Purg softmaker-freeoffice-2018 [2928]
```

Comment: How did you install it?  (you didn't provide a link though I suspect you may have intended to).  The way programs are removed/purged varies on how it was installed (snap, deb, compiled source, flatpak etc)

Comment: I think your questions been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/826758/1046152)

Comment: @guiverc

It was downloaded from its source site, then installed following instructions. The instruction was to run the program only, there was no installation package.

https://www.freeoffice.com/en/download/applications

Comment: @Mark

For me, this instruction did not helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to run this command to see what will happen:

```
sudo apt purge $(dpkg --list | grep softmaker | awk '{print $2}') --dry-run
```

Then, if no important system packages are being removed, run this command without `--dry-run` option.

Use `dpkg --list | grep softmaker` to see what packages associated with it in your system.

`dpkg --list | grep softmaker | awk '{print $2}'` command outputs only package names which is used in `sudo apt purge` as package names being removed.

If only one package would be removed (softmaker), then run the command without `--dry-run` option to remove it:

```
sudo apt purge $(dpkg --list | grep softmaker | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: The output is 

dpkg --list | grep softmaker
ii  softmaker-freeoffice-2018                  2928                                       amd64        SoftMaker FreeOffice is a complete office suite.

Comment: The output of the command
dpkg --list | grep softmaker

is 

ii  softmaker-freeoffice-2018                  2928                                       amd64        SoftMaker FreeOffice is a complete office suite.

Comment: The first command
sudo apt purge $(dpkg --list | grep softmaker | awk '{print $2}') --dry-run

output is 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  softmaker-freeoffice-2018*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Purg softmaker-freeoffice-2018 [2928]

Comment: I've updated my answer. The last command will purge it. It seems, dpkg command you've used couldn't remove it completely.

Comment: Yes, omitting --dry-run helped uninstalling the package. Thank you and greetings @Gryu